# Query to get number of % sign = length of string in the next row in Oracle 10g

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

is there any SQL query in Oracle10G which can give the desired output as given required in below sample.
Query should print the name first and in the second row it should print the "%" equal in number with the length of the string.

Could you please help?

Below is the sample of table column

```
JIM
JOHN
MICHAEL
```

and the output should come like below :

```
JIM
%%%
JOHN
%%%%
MICHAEL
%%%%%%%
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would normally be considered an issue for presentation logic, not database logic.  However, one option would be to use `union all`, and then `length` and `rpad` to get the correct number of `%` signs.  You'd also need to establish a row number to keep the order together.

Here's one approach:

```
select name
from (
  select name, rownum rn
  from yourtable
  union all
  select rpad('%', length(name), '%') name, rownum + 1 rn
  from yourtable ) t
order by rn, name
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a816bf/1)

Answer (score 0):

you can check this link
http://www.club-oracle.com/articles/oracle-pivoting-row-to-column-conversion-techniques-sql-166/

there are many options discussed, it will help